# Why does realpath() return error EEXIST?

Tags: c++, error-handling, realpath

My program is running in a Linux environment, compiled with gcc version 4.4.7.

I am using `realpath()` to "canonicalize" file paths.  The path of every directory and file I feed to `realpath()` definitely exists, which of course is essential for `realpath()` to work properly.

However, sometimes `realpath()` will fail with error code 17, name `EEXIST`, string description "File exists".

That baffles me.  Of course it exists, I scream at `realpath()`.   But `realpath()` is unmoved by my ranting.

Documentation for `realpath()` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html lists the errors that cause it to fail, but `EEXIST` is not one of them.

Why does `realpath()` fail in this way?

Examples of directory and file paths that cause the `EEXIST` error:

- An absolute path to a directory:  `/alpha/bravo/charlie/delta`
- An absolute path to a file:  `/alpha/bravo/charlie/foo.txt`
- A relative path to a file:  `../../charlie/foo.txt`
- A path to a file that has a extra dot in it:  `/alpha/bravo/Charlie/./foo.txt`

But those examples are not definitive, because other files with those exact same patterns, and in the same directories, will succeeed.

There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason to what directory or file will cause the `EEXIST` error.  The error typically only happens for the first file path I try to canonicalize, and then not for subsequent ones.  However, I cannot kludge around it by merely trying to canonicalize that first file again;  the error will keep happening just for it.

Program snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>    // for PATH_MAX

using std;

string PathCanonicalize( string const & path )
{
  string result;

  char szResult[ PATH_MAX ];
  ::realpath( path.c_str(), szResult );
  if ( errno == EEXIST )
  {
    // Why?
    cerr << "realpath: error code " << errno << ", " << ::strerror( errno ) << ": '" << path << "'.  Of course the file exists!" << endl;

    result = path;
  }
  else if ( errno )
  {
    cerr << "realpath: error code " << errno << ", " << ::strerror( errno ) << ": '" << path << "'" << endl;

    result = path;
  }
  else
  {
    result = szResult;
  }

  return result;      
}
```

Comment: It is buggy code, you must *only* check `errno` if the function returns NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never, ever check `errno` without a specific reason.

Perhaps whatever internal operation `realpath` happened to do last failed with `EEXIST`. Or maybe `errno` happened to be `EEXIST` from some previous operation that failed and `realpath` didn't change it.

If this didn't cause `realpath` to fail, why do you care?

From your own link:

> Upon successful completion, realpath() shall return a pointer to the resolved name. **Otherwise**, realpath() shall return a null pointer and set errno to indicate the error, and the contents of the buffer pointed to by resolved_name are undefined.

Notice it doesn't say that `errno` is set to anything in particular if `realpath` succeeds. So why are you checking `errno` before checking if `realpath` succeeded?

Comment: To add, not related to `realpath` directly but in general, a few rare functions don't have a return value that indicates an error and checking `errno` is the only way to determine whether the operation succeeded. But even for those functions, `errno` is not cleared on success. If you want to check `errno` for those functions, you need to explicitly set `errno` to zero before calling those functions. (As this answer rightly points out: don't do that except when the function is supposed to be used like that. `realpath` is allowed to set `errno` even if the only error is some internal error.)

Comment: Good point.   I was checking for null a few edits ago, but I recombobulated it incorrectly when something else was going wrong.   Thanks.

Comment: @MikeFinch, hehe, thx for that word. :) (Found e.g. at the English Learners SX [sister site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78358/4015): _"Discombobulate is the original nonsense word. It was an invented word. It means 'to destroy, tear apart, fragment'. So to re-combobulate is to recombine, make good what was destroyed, or to undo a bad action."_)

Answer (score -1):

That is, you shouldn't think the realpath() been failed/succeeded by checking the 'errno' value, you should check its returned value against the NULL. If NULL returned, then you can check the 'errno' to dive the root cause.
In other words, if realpath() succeed, it might not change/reset/clear the 'errno' value - assign 0 for it. Only when failed, it will set 'errno' as the error code.

Comment: You just re wrting the accepeted answer.